# RPM build dependencies error

Tags: dependencies, rpm, rpmbuild

I am trying to create a binary RPM file on Cent OS 6.5 but am running into errors during the prep stage. My spec file has the following commands in the prep section:

```
%prep
%setup -q
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum -y install python-pip
pip install ws4py request
```

But when i run:

```
 rpmbuild -v -bb --clean SPECS/ttsdk.spec
```

I get the following output:

```
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Kkbk09 (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Kkbk09 (%prep
```

It seems like it is failing because the package is already installed, which would not be the behavior I would expect. Am i overlooking something? Perhaps a way to make the rpm command not fail when already installed or have the spec file overlook a bad exit code? If the full log is needed or more of the spec file, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `-U` instead of `-i`?

Try using `yum install ...` instead of `rpm`?

If all else fails add `|| :` to the end of that line to always have it return true.

That all being said that seems a bad thing for a spec file to be doing during `%prep` to me (and requires building as root which is generally discouraged).

Comment: Etan, Thank you. The first two suggestions did not work (although I did switch to yum install instead of rpm), but the last one did work. I feel this is a workaround? It still seems odd to me that an already installed package causes a failure. Also, with regards to building as root, this is going to be an RPM that is meant to be deployed to VMs that should be on a fresh install so while I do heed the warnings, I'm less worried about messing anything up!

Comment: @MarkS The issue with root building is not a deployment concern. It is a build concern. You are trusting the spec file and build process to not do things they should not to your build system. Things like try to install packages, etc. actually. =) `yum install $pkg.rpm` seems to return 0 when it says there is nothing to do for me on CentOS 5 but `rpm -U` does seem to fail (which I agree is a bit odd). You could try `--replacepkgs` to `rpm` but that's more work then you actually need in that case. You could also test for the package before trying to install it.